# Showing compatilibity of charts on generated by stereographic projections: showing that inverse of stereographic projection is $C^{\infty}$

Tags: differential-geometry, taylor-expansion, smooth-manifolds

I am working with the standard $n$-dimensional sphere $S^n = \{\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ s.t. } \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert = 1 \}$. Let $U = S^n\setminus \{(0, 0, ..., 1)\}$ (the set of all points minus a pole) and let $V = S^n\setminus \{(0, 0, ..., -1)\}$.

We can define the stereographic projection for $U$:

\begin{align}
    &\varphi(\mathbf{x}) : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \\
    &\varphi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{1 - x^{n+1}}(x_1,...,x_n)
\end{align}

Similarly the stereographic projection for $V$:

\begin{align}
    &\psi(\mathbf{x}) : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \\
    &\psi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{1 + x^{n+1}}(x_1,...,x_n)
\end{align}

I would like to show that the coordinate charts $(U, \varphi)$ and $(V, \psi)$ are compatible. Two charts are compatible if $U \cap V = \emptyset$ (clearly not the case) or if the compositions $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ and $\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}$ are both $C^{\infty}$: clearly, I must show the latter.

I have been able to compute the inverse of the stereographic projections:

\begin{align}
    &\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{y}) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow U \\
    &\varphi^{-1}(\mathbf{y}) = (\frac{2y_1}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y}\Vert^2},...,\frac{2y_n}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y}\Vert^2}, 1 - \frac{2}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y} \Vert ^2})
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    &\psi^{-1}(\mathbf{y}) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V \\
    &\psi^{-1}(\mathbf{y}) = (\frac{2y_1}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y}\Vert^2},...,\frac{2y_n}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y}\Vert^2}, \frac{2}{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y} \Vert ^2} - 1)
\end{align}

I could compose them, but that seems tedious to me, instead, I would like to use the fact that the composition of two $C^{\infty}$ function is also $C^{\infty}$. I have been able to show that $\varphi, \psi$ are $C^{\infty}$ as I can use the geometric series to quickly find a Taylor series for each component in order to show that the partial derivatives with respect to $x_{n + 1}$, and the other partials are easy as either I am taking the derivative of a linear function, or a constant function.

However, showing that the inverse functions are $C^{\infty}$ is tripping me up. I have to show that they have continuous partial derivatives of all orders, and I don't quite know how to write a nice Taylor series for the ${2}/{1 + \Vert \mathbb{y}\Vert^2}$ bit, it will have Hessians and tensors and all that, since it's a multivariable function.

What else could I do to show that the inverse is $C^{\infty}$? Or, is there an alternative strategy?

Comment: All the maps involved are rational functions in the variables $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Rational functions are always smooth where they are defined (where the denominators don't vanish, which you shouldn't have to worry about since the charts were chosen so this is satisfied)

Comment: @ Thanks--this is indeed it. One simply has to bite the bullet and compose the projections and their inverses, to see that they clean up quite beautifully into an even clearer rational function.